# How to read a .sav file in C?

Tags: python, c, dll, load

I created a logistic regression model in Python (Jupyter) which I transformed to .sav file through the following pickle function:

```
filename = 'model.sav'
pickle.dump(clf_lr, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

In Python I can load the model through:

```
loaded_model = pickle.load(open('model.sav', 'rb'))
```

and can make a prediction through:

```
prediction = loaded_model.predict([[0.37, 0.75]])
```

As I need a DLL file at the end, which is easy to create with C there arose the question: Is it possible to load the model.sav file also in C and make predictions with it? Please consider, that I don't have much experience with coding in C.

EDIT:
As suggested in the comments, it would be better to export my model to a .json or .csv file and import this in my c program. Does anybody have an example C program where a .json or .csv ML model is used? In the internet I only found ways to use it in e.g. java or javascript programs.

Comment: Of course it is possible, but the pickle format is not necessarily a good exchange format. If's fine for Python readers and writers, but if you need interoperability you should consider a more suitable format. But in this case I'm not sure if you should want to do this in C.

Comment: To properly interpret a pickle file, you need a Python interpreter. A C program to read it is one thing: a C program that will do something useful with it is a project that is more ambitious than you perhaps expect.

Comment: You mean a *pickle* file?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. @cheatah do you have a recommendation for a format, with which it is possible? Is there any possibility to exchange a pretrained model from python to a C program? (and also work with it in a useful way)

Comment: @Cori, stick to CSV or JSON. And don't write your own parser.